# Java Classes Not Found In WAR Module of a Multi Module Maven Application

Tags: java, maven, war, resteasy, ear

I had a multi module application called ParentApp(Which is a parent project) and it has JARMOdule, WARModule, EARModule. EAR Module has dependedncies of JARModule and WARMOdule

ParentPOM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ParentApp</groupId>
<artifactId>ParentApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
<module>JARModule</module>
<module>WARModule</module>
<module>EARModule</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

EARModule POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>ParentApp</groupId>
<artifactId>ParentApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>EARModule</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ParentAPP</groupId>
    <artifactId>WARModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ParentAPP</groupId>
    <artifactId>JARModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And respective JAR and WAR Poms which doesn't have any dependecies, WARModule is a WebApp, I had a class in WARModule when i build the ParentApp with mvn clean install

under target folder under classes i still have [image]

I'm basically trying to have a rest service in WARModule but unable to make it work, any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the Maven [standard folder structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).
You should put all your java code inside src/main/java folder.
Looking at the image you uploaded, it looks like the SampleApp.java is not present in the correct directory as expected by maven.